# Are Parse Counters Multi-threaded?

Tags: ios, multithreading, parse-platform, increment, decrement

I am creating an app that will increment/decrement a value by 1 or 2 based on responses from users. If multiple users try to change the value at the same time, will it work correctly? My example code is:

```
PFObject *gameScore = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[gameScore setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1337] forKey:@"score"];
[gameScore saveInBackground];
```

If multiple people try to change the "score" at the same time, will the score be accurate after all of the calls are completed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this won't work. You have a race condition where a client may not know about the changes made by the other client, if you're explicitly setting the new score as above in your code sample.

What you can do to solve this is by using the "increment" function. This sends a command to the server to atomically increment the server value by a certain amount, so the clients don't actually need to care about what the value is they send it - they just increase it by a certain amount. The server handles the atomic nature of the request, and avoids the race conditions you'd see if you were explicitly setting the score.

```
[gameScore incrementKey:@"score"];
[gameScore saveInBackground];
```

or if you want to increment by more than 1...

```
[gameScore incrementKey:@"score" byAmount:@(2)];
[gameScore saveInBackground];
```

Comment: Hi there, just want to know if you had tested this or have any sources on this?

Comment: Yes, look under the heading "Counters" in the Objects section in the Parse documentation. https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects It states that the incrementKey call is atomic. If you find its not working, then you should lodge a bug with them.